# Shorthand for calling a function with an argument more than once in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function with an argument, e.g:

```
function doThisThing(toThis){
    // some function
}
```

So far I've been calling the function multiple times with different arguments like this:

```
doThisThing ( bananas );
doThisThing ( apples );
doThisThing ( pears );
```

Is there a way of doing this more succinctly? I've tried things like `doThisThing ( bananas, apples, pears );` and so on, but to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[bananas, apples, pears].forEach(doThisThing);
```

works if you can rely on `Array.prototype.forEach` support and `doThisThing` only takes one argument.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point but

```
[bananas, apples, pears].forEach(doThisThing);
```

Code being concise is a good thing, but it's also important for it to not be weird.

Now, if `doThisThing(banana)` etc are things you do *a lot*, then you can create pre-arranged shortcuts:

```
var doBanana = doThisThing.bind(undefined, banana); // etc
```

Then `doBanana()` is equivalent to `doThisThing(banana);`. This can be handy when you've got functions that take more than one argument, and which are designed such that the first argument has few variations but the second argument has many. You can create a bound version with a pre-supplied value for the first argument, and then the argument(s) passed in to that will succeed the "fixed" pre-arranged value.